# Nhibernate take skip not producing correct sql

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate, informix, linq-to-nhibernate

Considoring the following query:

```
session.Query<Brand>()
       .Where(x => x.Name == "Clause")
       .Select(a => a.Name)
       .Take(10)
       .ToList();
```

NHibernate is not generating the correct SQL - it does not appear to be adding the limiters and appears to be generating the take in code - not in SQL.

Any Ideas?

Generated SQL:

```
select brand0_.br_name as col_0_0_ from Brands brand0_
 where brand0_.br_name=?;p0 = 'Clause'
```

Comment: Not being well versed in these things - is it possible to reverse the calls to `Take` and `Select`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm pretty sure that would bring back the whole of the record and not just the name, worse performance with no difference. Stuart what is the EXACT code you're using to execute the query? and what version of NHibernate? As the code above isn't actually being resolved (there isn't a ToList or alternative). I tried a very similar query and it worked with this output: select TOP (@p0) fundingpac0_.EffectiveDate as col_0_0_ from FundingPackage fundingpac0_ where fundingpac0_.DeletedDate is null;@p0 = 10 [Type: Int32 (0)]

Comment: The semi-colon near the end (but not at the end) of the SQL is problematic; it certainly leaves the material after the semi-colon as invalid Informix SQL.  I see nothing corresponding to the 'Take(10)'.

Comment: did you resolved this? I'm having the same situation with postgresql, maybe the Take() method is not implemented correctly in the dialect? I dont know..

Comment: Hi Pablote, I found the best way to resolve this was to use HQL, it produces SQL that virtually matches what you've written, and it's still cross SQL engine!

LINQ, I've found, is very subjective, and can provide very unusual results if you don't write them properly..

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a such code and it's got "TOP" in SQL. (NHibernate version 3.1)

@mattytommo is right, you've forgot about "List()":

```
session.Query<Brand>()
       .Where(x => x.Name == "Clause")
       .Select(a => a.Name)
       .Take(10)
       .List();
```

Have you used QueryOver ?

Comment: Oh sorry! I was using a ToList() but some how forgot about it in my example... (updated!)

I'm using  3.1.0.4000 but I'm using a Informix database....

Comment: That's mean You've used NHibernateLinq provider, but I try with QueryOver on SqlServer. But you can try it with change "session.Query<Brand>" to "session.QueryOver<Brand>()".

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use QueryOver, as that returns a specif NH type, I need to return a IQueryable...